# How to hook NTShutdownSystem in C# in order to differentiate between shutdown and reboot

Tags: c#, hook, shutdown, reboot, shutdown-hook

unfortunatly, when you listen to WM_QUERYENDSESSION, you do not get the information if the user has requested a reboot or a shutdown. This is really bad design, but it's the way Windows is, so I was thinking of hooking the call to NTShutdownSystem, which gets a parameter telling the system to perform a reboot or to shutdown.

The question is: how can this actually be achieved in C#? I want to get some kind of hook that I can use to determine the parameters passed to NTShutdownSystem, and then save that information. After that, I want to call the "real" NTShutdownSystem the way it was intended by the user.

Do you have any sample code illustrating this?

Comment: I like this question, I had to do something similar a few months ago and in essence gave up :/  Would be very interested in the answer

Comment: Do you know if the method is called by the user process?  Given the name of the function I am leaning towards no?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` does not give a shutdown reason is that the user may just be logging out at that time, rather than shutting down the system.

This generally falls under the category of *kernel level hooking* and has generally not been considered a good thing as it can influence stability of the system. Most of them are written in C or C++, and generally have to go to a lot of effort to perform the hook across all the programs that are executing - e.g. hooking the routines at program load-time.

This is not a trivial, but there are some frameworks that have been written to help with trying to [hook routines like this](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) using managed code (e.g. C#)

The next question to ask is why do you care?

**edit** NTShutdownSystem is invoked very late in the shutdown process - at that point you probably have no UI and no way of doing anything. I would recommend intercepting [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [InitiateShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [InitiateSystemShutdownEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - I don't know if some of them are called by the other, but you should probably only record the reason and then react to the reason in the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` code of your standard app.

Comment: Hi,I do get the notification from WM_QUERYENDSESSION if the user logs off (the system sets a value in lparam)or does a shutdown, but when a shutdown is performed, I do not get if the system is rebooted or completely shutdown. I definitely need to know it because I do run a shutdown script that needs to behave differently depending ig the user does a shutdown or reboot.

Comment: If you want the information, you will have to hook the routine. I don't have any example code as hooking is a non-trivial task, nost of which is scaffolding.

Comment: One final thing - the invocation of NTShutdownSystem happens incredibly late in the shutdown process - you're probably not going to have any UI left. You may be better off intercepting ExitWindowsEx or InitiateShutdown or it's ilk